# Calling a Method on all Objects in a List?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a List playerList with a method GoSomething() on the component PlayerScript. I know I can do:

```
foreach(Player player in playerList) {
  player.GetComponent<PlayerScript>().DoSomething();
}
```

But this results in quite a lot of foreach loops when working with lists. So is there a one-liner for calling a method for all objects in a list? Something like:

```
playerList.GetComponent<PlayerScript>().DoSomething();
```

Comment: You just might want to put all of it into one line (see also https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Lists`'s `ForEach` method:

`playerList.ForEach(player => player.GetComponent<PlayerScript>().DoSomething())`

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=netframework-4.8) is more

Comment: Note that `GetComponent` is always slow and internally this is like a `foreach` loop anyway .. it is written in one line but it will never be faster than simply using a `foreach`